# pclose() won't give me the process exit code

Tags: c++, linux, process, exit-code

I've got a strange problem here.

I wrote some C++ code with uses `popen(3)`, `read(3)` and `pclose(3)` to run various shell commands, parse their output, and do some other stuff. The program seems to work well.

Then I extracted some of the code into a shared library and tried to use it from a C# program running under Mono. Now the C++ code doesn't work at all.

Running the code in GDB, it seems that `pclose(3)` *always* unconditionally returns -1 rather than the *real* exit code of the child process.

Watching `strace`, it seems that `wait4(2)` fails with `ECHILD`. And, as best as I can tell, it does that because `SIGCHLD` is being delivered to one of Mono's other threads, which promptly does several `wait4(2)` calls, and then carries on with its day.

Doing some Google searching, it appears the kernel chooses a thread at random to send `SIGCHLD` to. (In other words, in a multithreaded program it is guaranteed to *always* choose the "wrong" thread.)

Obviously I have no control over what the Mono runtime decides to do. So how can I invoke external processes and reliably get their exit codes?

Comment: was reported to Mono here, they closed as "resolved as  FEATURE".  https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=21818

Comment: ...and then decided to change it after all, three months later? https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/6200

Answer (score 2):

`pclose()` never returns the real exit code from the child process.

`pclose` rather returns the value of the `stat_loc` parameter to the `wait()` call.

In cases, when `waitpid()` with the process id of the child returns `-1`, `pclose()` returns `-1` as well.

This may happen if you have broken code in other threads that waits for arbitrary child processes instead of only waiting for self created child processes.